# Linux Overgrive Error

Tags: python, linux

I get the following error when attempting to sync on overgrive:

```
[INFO] Linux-3.13.0-24-generic-x86_64-with-LinuxMint-17-qiana
[INFO] Desktop : default
[CONFIG] Loading User Settings GUI mode
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "overgrive.py", line 5237, in doFullGoogleDriveSync
  File "overgrive.py", line 4981, in processGoogleDrive
  File "overgrive.py", line 4418, in processGooglePath
  File "overgrive.py", line 4576, in processGoogleDocsToLocal
  File "overgrive.py", line 3480, in downloadAndConvertGoogleDoc
KeyError: 'application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet'
```

Googling "KeyError: 'application..." produced no useful results